# Is there a way to force all property name maps to use ALL CAPS in EF 4.3 Code-First?

Tags: c#, oracle, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I'm using EF 4.3 code-first with an Oracle database. One weird thing about the database is that it automatically makes table and column names ALL CAPS. My domain properties are in PascalCase. Unfortunately, EF doesn't know to capitalize column names, so my queries don't work. I have hundreds of properties on several classes that should map to oracle columns. I would really rather not manually code all those mappings. Is there a way to use a convention to capitalize column names?

**SUMMARY:**

I need for Entity Framework to use ALL CAPS for all column names. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tried this, but what about something like this:

```
public class SomeEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Code First to ignore ColumnTypeCasing convention
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ColumnTypeCasingConvention>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, how I wish the conventions were not only removable, but also editable like they are with (Fluent) NHibernate.

Comment: They're currently planning to add it (http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1155529-ability-to-plug-in-custom-conventions-for-schema-g), but please go and vote for it so that maybe they won't decide to cut it (again).

Comment: Where is `ColumnTypeCasingConvention` located? When I include `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions` it still doesn't resolve the reference.

Comment: This solution works until version 5 of EF. On version 6 it became obsolete.

Comment: What is the namespace for ColumnTypeCasingConvention? @RogersonNazário did they replace it?